# 2000 member server, 2003 FFL/DFL, only 2012 DC

Tags: active-directory

I have a 2000 member server in a 2003 FFL/DFL domain with a 2003 DC.  I'm hoping to stand up a new 2012R2 DC, transfer fsmo roles and demote the 2003DC.

If I keep the FFL/DFL at 2003, will the 2000 member server still be able to authenticate once I only have 2012 DCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Windows O.S. starting with Windows 2000 will be able to authenticate against *any* Active Directory domain controller; you can only have issues if you still have NT 4.0 systems lingering around, because they only support old-style NTLM authentication which is not in use anymore on recent DCs.

That said, you really shouldn't keep Windows 2000 systems around, if at all possible.